# How to use Spritesheet Animation in qt Creater?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to qt create and I would like to use SpriteSheet Animation

I have used the following code from this article [Click Here](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2010/07/sprite-animation-from-sprite-sheet-in.html)

and I'm getting the following error [Please click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSGV2.png)

```
    class Sprite
{
public:

    Sprite();

    void draw( QPainter* painter);

    QPoint pos() const;

    void nextFrame();

private:

    QPixmap* mSpriteImage;
    int mCurrentFrame;
    QPoint mPos;
    int mXDir;

};

Sprite::Sprite():mPos(0,0),mCurrentFrame(0)
{
    mSpriteImage = new QPixmap(":dragon.png");
}

void Sprite::draw( QPainter* painter)
{
    painter->drawPixmap ( mPos.x(),mPos.y(), *mSpriteImage,
                                   mCurrentFrame, 0, 100,100 );
}

QPoint Sprite::pos() const
{
    return mPos;
}

void Sprite::nextFrame()
{
    //following variable keeps track which
    //frame to show from sprite sheet
    mCurrentFrame += 100;
    if (mCurrentFrame >= 500 )
        mCurrentFrame = 0;
    mPos.setX( mPos.x() + 10 );
}
```

Comment: Please take the trouble to include the text of the message in your question.  Offsite links may cease to exist at some point.

Answer (score 0):

include QPixmap in your file you should be fine

Comment: Better to add some details in the answer :)